# GCR Cloud Run says "Image [name] not found"

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to take my first baby steps with podman (instead of Docker) and Google Cloud Run. I've managed to build an image with a `gcr.io` tag and push it to Google. I then create a new service, and I can select the image in the "Select Image URL" pop-up dialog. But then the service fails to start, saying "Image [full name] not found".

I can't find anything on Google's support pages, or anywhere else. I can pull the image, I can push new versions, and they appear on the pop-up dialog. But the service still reports that they can't be found.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** in answer to DazWilkin's questions below:

> Can you run the podman-created container locally using Docker?

I can't run Docker locally because it is not compatible with Fedora 31 (hence podman). But I can run it locally using `podman run`

> Can you deploy a Docker-created container in Cloud Run?

As above: F31. However podman is supposed to be a drop-in replacement.

> Is the container registry in the same project as Cloud Run?

Yes. I did have a problem with that, but I got a permissions message rather than "not found".

> Have you tried deploying via gcloud rather than the console?

Yes.

```
$ podman push eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob c7f3d2e0289b done  
Copying blob def7032cea8e done  
Copying config f1c2e2615f done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures

$ gcloud run deploy --image eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world --platform managed
Service name (hs-hello-world):  
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [hs-hello-world] in project [my-project] region [europe-west1]
X Deploying... Image 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world' not found.                     
  X Creating Revision... Image 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world' not found.           
  . Routing traffic...                                                                             
Deployment failed                                                                                  
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Image 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world' not found.
```

When I used a Google-built container it worked fine.

**Update: 5 March 2020**

In the end I just carried on with the Google build service, and it works fine. My initial wish for local builds was in large part because a build on Google was taking over half an hour (lots of Haskell libraries to import), but now I've figured out how to use staged builds and multi-processor VMs to avoid this. I appreciate the efforts of those who have tried to help, but right now it's not broke so I'm not going to try to fix it.

Comment: Can you run the podman-created container locally using Docker? Can you deploy a Docker-created container in Cloud Run? Is the container registry in the same project as Cloud Run? Have you tried deploying via `gcloud` rather than the console? If so, please include the commands in the question.

Comment: Could you share the steps you follow to install podman to Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: @NibrassHaider Not quite sure what you mean. I'm running podman locally and then pushing the resulting container up to gcloud.

Comment: Could you try to add the latest tag while pushing to the container registry?  podman push eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world:latest (in order to discard that it could be the issue). and try to pull like following: gcloud run deploy --image eu.gcr.io/my-project/hs-hello-world

Comment: @André Breda's answer is working and should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue: it seems Cloud Run is picky about the kind of manifest it can pull.

By building my images with `--format docker` and pushing them with `--remove-signatures` (inspired by [this issue](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/2317)), podman will create and push docker-style manifests to the Container Registry and everything ran smoothly!

Too bad I spent a lot of time thinking it was a lack of permissions problem

Comment: Thank you! If anyone encounters the same problem, note that if you use "latest" image version you may want to use, instead, the exact "@sha256" version when re-deploying with the new image in a "docker" format. In my case I was using "latest" and Cloud Run didn't pull the new version immediately after I have republished it. I assume this has nothing to do with Cloud Run itself (rather seems like Container Registry specifics), but I was almost ready to dismiss this solution as not working before I realized that it didn't really try to use the new image version.

Comment: @Tim oh well done ! thanks for your reminder.
when deploying a cloud run using the --image argument, you need to push the image with "latest" tag to Artifact Registry. 

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#push-tagged

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My issue was that I was using the `docker/setup-buildx-action` in a GitHub action. When this was removed, Cloud Run was happy with the resulting manifest / container image.

Thanks to @André-Breda for providing the direction.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same issue today. I'm using buildah to create the new image. I realized that the image I used successfully yesterday was built as root. So I built the new one as root and pushed it successfully.

Wish I knew why. The images built as my username ran fine locally with rootless podman.